# Can Sharepoint 2010 / Adobe iFilter search results link to specific pages in PDF files?

Tags: search, search-results, pdf, ifilter

I have Adobe iFilter installed in SharePoint Foundation 2010, and PDF files are appearing in the search result hits.  If you click on the link, it opens the PDF file but not to the correct page where the text match was found.

Is there a way to make search result links open to specific PDF pages?

In other words, the URL in the search result hit would include a: `#page=[page number]` extension.

Comment: Did either of these answer your question? If so can you please mark one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that bookmarks are already defined in the PDF documents you would need to employ the Adobe PDF Parameters syntax described here http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf.

Excerpts from the actual document as examples:

**URL Examples**

- http://example.org/doc.pdf#nameddest=Chapter6
- http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=3
- http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=3&zoom=200,250,100
- http://example.org/doc.pdf#zoom=50
- http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=72&view=fitH,100
- http://example.org/doc.pdf#view=fitb&nameddest=Chapter3

**URL Limitations**

- Only one digit following a decimal point is retained for float
  values.
- Individual parameters, together with their values    (separated by &
  or #), can be no  greater then 32 characters in    length.
- You cannot use the reserved characters =, #, and &. There    is no
  way to escape these  special characters.
- If you turn bookmarks off using a URL parameter when a document had
  previously    been  saved with bookmarks on, the bookmark scroll-bars
  are displayed    at first, and only  disappear once Acrobat obtains
  enough streamed    information to render the full page

As an example on implementing these concepts in a real example see http://www.novolocus.com/2008/05/15/hit-highlighting-inside-adobe-pdfs-using-sharepoint-search/

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that I can put these extensions in myself to make links to specific PDF file pages.  But I'm asking if the links that appear on the Sharepoint search results page can be made to point inside PDF documents.

Comment: I believe this link http://www.novolocus.com/2008/05/15/hit-highlighting-inside-adobe-pdfs-using-sharepoint-search/ shows how you can reach deep-content, but you still need to change the Core Search Results Web parts yourself

Comment: Thanks, Marius.  I was expecting some way for the Sharepoint search engine to decide which page you should jump to in the PDF file.  The link you shared gives a very different approach to this problem.  I might end up using this!  But for now, I want to see if there are any other solutions.  I would upvote your answer, but by karma is below threshold.

Comment: These are complementary solutions, as the 2nd is simply relying on explanations provided in my answer (i've updated to include this too).

Comment: Do you think there's a way of getting the PDF page number where Sharepoint found the hit, and using it in the template?  That would use your solution idea to get the result I'm looking for...

Comment: With simple enterprise search, not sure, unless you build your own Core Search Results and parse results too build the proper URL as described above. Maybe FAST could help more, but i'm not really mastering that!

Answer (score 0):

Not in SharePoint 2010. The indexing was dependent on older iFilter technology. Not on 2013/2016 even though you get "deep linking" for Word and PowerPoint with the Format Handlers, PDF is not included.